# How do I install Ubuntu on an HP dv6-7206 Tx notebook?

Tags: 12.04, hp

I am trying to install ubuntu 12.04 on new hp notebook nb pc dv6-7205 tx. This notebook comes with windows 8 preloaded.

Itried to install ubuntu 12.04 but while rebooting the boot loader does not show both the operating systems and second thing is if only ubuntu is loaded on this laptop I don't know how to configure wireless/bluetooth Is there any step by step guide available.

Comment: Are you attempting to setup **dual-boot**, or replace Windows 8 with **Ubuntu**?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have burned Ubuntu to a CD or a USB stick. You need to enable the computer to look for other boot devices than the hard disc first. This can be a bit technical. You will need to enter the BIOS, which is a menu controlling hardware of the computer. If you are not experienced with this, I would recommend that you find someone, who is, or look closely in the handbook following the notebook for instructions. What needs to be changed is the 'boot order', making sure that the CD drive (or USB) is checked before the hard disc.

Concerning wireless, it should tell you that there are wireless coneections available, when you open the computer. After entering the password, it should work. There is a guide here: https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-help/net-wireless.html

Similar for Bluetooth: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BluetoothSetup

Answer (score 0):

I just bought HP DV6-7210US. I thought our computers could potentially vary quite a bit, but my problems were solved but going to HP and updating the BIOS. I was then able to use/install UEFI/Legacy at the same time. This might help you to see what you are looking for.